# jQuery: Cycle through elements to create combo variations

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, foreach

**Premise:** An eCommerce system with variations.

Example HTML markup for use in this question.

```
<div class = "variationType" data-variation-type = "size">
    <h3>Colour</h3>
    <div class = "variation" data-variation-type = "size"> small </div>
    <div class = "variation" data-variation-type = "size"> large </div>
</div>

<div class = "variationType" data-variation-type = "colour">
    <h3>Colour</h3>
    <div class = "variation" data-variation-type = "colour"> red </div>
    <div class = "variation" data-variation-type = "colour"> blue </div>
</div>

<div class = "variationType" data-variation-type = "material">
    <h3>Material</h3>
    <div class = "variation" data-variation-type = "material"> stone </div>
    <div class = "variation" data-variation-type = "material"> wood </div>
</div>
```

What I need to do is cycle through each of the above variation types and variation names to create a list of all possible variation combos (at least one variation from each variation type). This is stupid easy if there are only two variation types, but I'd need this to work with 3+ as well.

My thinking is that I need to somehow implement a pathing algorithm to go through each variation type and create the unique list, but I don't know how to do this.

In order to get the total amount of possible variations, I am doing the following.

```
// figure out how many variations there needs to be
var totalPathsToTake = 0;
var totalPathsTaken = 0;
jQuery('.variationType').each(function(i) {
    var variationType = jQuery(this).attr("data-variation-type");
    var totalVariationsInType = jQuery('.variation[data-variation-type="' + variationType + '"]').length;

    if(totalPathsToTake == 0){
        totalPathsToTake = totalPathsToTake + totalVariationsInType;
    } else {
        totalPathsToTake = totalPathsToTake * totalVariationsInType;
    }
});
console.log("total variations " + totalPathsToTake)
```

So the above code will respond with `8`, which is correct.

**The problem is, now what?** How would I go about creating these variations? Any help or advice is insanly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, what you want is all the permutations of div.variations.

One way to do it is to realize that as we permute one variation type we are always reusing the permutations of the variation types that follow it. This lends itself to a recursive implementation like this:

```js
// make an array of variation types, and each entry is the list of possible values
const all = $('.variationType').map((i, el) => $('.variation', el)).toArray();

// recursive function, return all permutations of values for a array of variation types
function permute_variations(arr) {
  // base case of no variation types
  if (arr.length < 1)
    return [];
  // base case of a single variation type
  if (arr.length === 1)
    return arr[0].toArray();

  // recurse by getting the permutations of the following variation types
  const inner_arr = permute_variations(arr.slice(1));
  // now permute all values for this type with the permutations that we got
  return arr[0].map((i, v0) => inner_arr.map(e => [v0].concat(e))).toArray();
}

const result = permute_variations(all);
console.log(`Number of permutations: ${result.length}`);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="variationType" data-variation-type="size">
  <h3>Colour</h3>
  <div class="variation" data-variation-type="size"> small </div>
  <div class="variation" data-variation-type="size"> large </div>
</div>

<div class="variationType" data-variation-type="colour">
  <h3>Colour</h3>
  <div class="variation" data-variation-type="colour"> red </div>
  <div class="variation" data-variation-type="colour"> blue </div>
</div>

<div class="variationType" data-variation-type="material">
  <h3>Material</h3>
  <div class="variation" data-variation-type="material"> stone </div>
  <div class="variation" data-variation-type="material"> wood </div>
</div>
```

The result is an array of triples of div.variation elements and you can process it as you like.

Note: be careful of the difference between the Array map() method and the jQuery map() method, as you can see they call the lambda function with the index and element parameters in opposite order.

Comment: You are my hero! I just implemented this logic into my code, and it seems to be exactly what I needed. I wish I could give you two upvotes because my previous written solution was fairly close to yours, but didn't work. Seeing your implimentation was exactly what I needed to show me where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native English speaker

so I can't explain it well

but I'll try my best

that would be appreciated if there's any suggestion

First, I simplify the problem to find combinations of two array

```
var arr1 = ["0","1"]
var arr2 = ["0","1"]
```

and we all know that the results would be like:
(first char comes from arr1)
(last char comes from arr2)

- 00
- 01
- 10
- 11

Then I change the values of the second array to

```
var Second = ["0","1","2"]
```

the results are:

- 00
- 01
- 02
- 10
- 11
- 12

after this, I add another array

```
var Third = ["0","1"]
```

the results are:

- 000
- 001
- 010
- 011
- 020
- 021
- 100
- 101
- 110
- 111
- 120
- 121

I found there's a logic to determine how many times would a single num repeat and whole array values repeat

We can calculate the combinations simply by multiple each array's length

(if array's length is greater than 0)

> a single num would repeat `combinations / previous array's length product` times
>
> and whole array values would repeat `combinations / all previous array's length product(including self)`

when combinations is 4 in case 1, last char repeat 1 time since there's no previous array

first char repeat `4 / First.length = 2` times

when combinations is 12 in case 3, the last array of result repeat `12/First.length = 6` times

first array repeat `12/(First.length * Second.length * Third.length) = 1` times

so here it is, hope this helps

```js
var Result = []
var Final = []
var Combinations = 1

var First = ["0", "1", "2"]
var Empty = []
var Second = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
var Third = ["+", "-"]

// assume there would be some empty array
var allList = [First, Second, Empty, Third].filter(n => n.length>0).reverse() // remove empty array and reverse

allList.forEach(arr => Combinations = arr.length > 0 ? Combinations * arr.length : Combinations) // calculate combinations
$("body").append("Combinations : " + Combinations + "<br>")

var Items = 1
var totalRepeatTimes = 1
var elementRepeatTimes = 1
allList.forEach((arr ,index) => {
    Items *= arr.length;
    // array repeat times
    totalRepeatTimes = Combinations/Items;

    // each char repeat times
    elementRepeatTimes = index > 0 ? elementRepeatTimes * allList[index - 1].length : elementRepeatTimes;
    
    // add result array to Final
    Final.push(RepeatArray(arr, elementRepeatTimes, totalRepeatTimes))
})

Result = Array(Combinations).fill("."); // prepare an array fill with empty string
Final.reverse().forEach(arr => { Result = Join(Result, arr) }) // Join all result array

Result.forEach((result, index)=> $("body").append((index+1) + " : " + result + "<br>") )

function RepeatArray(arr, elementRepeatTimes, totalRepeatTimes) {
    arr = RepeatElement(arr, elementRepeatTimes);
    arr = RepeatTotal(arr, totalRepeatTimes);
    return arr;
}

function RepeatElement(arr, elementRepeatTimes) {
    var newArr = [];
    arr.forEach(element => {
        for (var i = 0; i < elementRepeatTimes; i++) {
            newArr.push(element)
        }
    })
    return newArr;
}

function RepeatTotal(arr, totalRepeatTimes) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < totalRepeatTimes; i++) {
        newArr = newArr.concat(arr)
    }
    return newArr;
}

function Join(arr1, arr2) {
    var newArr = [];
    arr1.forEach((element, index) => {
        newArr.push(arr1[index].toString() + arr2[index].toString())
    })
    return newArr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```